# Multi Step form tesitng in Jmeter

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, jmeter

How can we test multi step form in Jmeter ?

We have total three steps in our form wizard, we have to test the first form step, after submitting the first form step, second step occur and then after submitting the second step third step occur.

Comment: for every form are you sending new http request? if yes then simple recording would work just create multiple transaction controllers for each form to differentiate requests and analysis later.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a prob, if you have three request. If you have one request for all of this form, anyway you'll send one request to the server.

If you need to extract some expressions from one request to use it in another, use [Regexp](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [XPath Extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

But,the simplest way to write script is to use [HTTP Proxy Server (HTTP Test Script Recorder)](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server).